# function composition with Text.Printf.printf

Tags: haskell, printf, ghc, polyvariadic

I would like to define a logger function, like

```
myPutStrLn = putStrLn . (++) "log: "
main = do myPutStrLn "hello"
```

which is fine. Now I want to format the provided String with `printf`, like this

```
myPutStrLn $ printf "test %d" (23 :: Int)
```

Great! Since I have this pattern very often I want to factor `printf` into the logger function:

```
myPrintf = logger . printf
  where
    -- note, this is just an example. should be
    -- replaceable with any function with this
    -- typesignature
    logger :: String -> IO ()
    logger = putStrLn . (++) "log: "

main = myPrintf "test %d" (23 :: Int)
```

Unfortunately, this fails with

```
The function `myPrintf' is applied to two arguments,
but its type `String -> IO ()' has only one
In a stmt of a 'do' block: myPrintf "test %d" (23 :: Int)
In the expression: do { myPrintf "test %d" (23 :: Int) }
In an equation for `main':
    main = do { myPrintf "test %d" (23 :: Int) }
```

GHC infers `myPrintf :: String -> IO ()`, so there is obviously something wrong. I found something about [Polyvariadic composition](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/polyvariadic.html#polyvar-comp), but I'm not able to apply this to my problem. I'm not even sure if it would solve my problem.

The code is also available via [gist](https://gist.github.com/3465511).

Comment: If you don't mind changing the format string, you can do `printf . ("log: " ++)`.

Comment: myLog = putStrLn . printf . ("log: " ++) does not work imo (since myLog is of type String -> IO ())- one has to replicate vararg stuff to enable this.

Comment: @h_s: Yes, but `printf . ("log: " ++) :: PrintfType c => String -> c` and there's `PrintfType` instance for `IO a`.

Comment: @Vitus: ok i see. nice (essentially the same as the answer below)

Answer (score 1):

you can define your function by using hPrintf and the stdout handle.

Like that,  the result of the function myPrintf remain an instance of the class HPrintfType

```
myPrintf::  (HPrintfType c) => String -> c
myPrintf = (hPrintf stdout) . (printf "log:%s")

main = myPrintf "test %d" (23 :: Int)
```

---

The polyvariadic form for the printf function works only because you have this instance definition :

```
(PrintfArg a, PrintfType r) => PrintfType (a -> r).
```

at each new PrintfArg parameter, type inference return an PrintfType class type if possible.

For working your logger function would have the following type :

```
logger :: (PrintfType c) => String -> c
```

but the compilator wil fail because the function return an IO () and not the more generic typeclass PrintfType.

In my opinion, only a modification of the module Text.Printf could help you because you can't create new instance of PrintfType as some method are hidden

Comment: nice trick, but that's not what I wanted, is it?
see the comment above `logger` in my question. I want to use `printf` for formatting something to a String, and then put it somewhere into the IO world (not necessarily a handle, but for example into a global storage).

Comment: i have updated my answer to explain why for me is not possible